# Does copying files via MTP over USB compress them?

Tags: usb, backup, compression, mtp

I'm trying to backup my phone to a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I noticed that one of my backup images looked noticeably more pixelated, even when viewed at the same size as my phone screen.

This might be because I use a fairly old monitor, a Samsung syncmaster 204BW with DVI, but I'm not sure. It has a resolution of 1680 * 1050, and my phone has a 16 MP camera.

If copying through USB like I did does reduce the image quality, then how can I still backup my phone (preferably to something I have or can buy), and still have undamaged pictures? One more thing: I'm using a USB 3.0 port and cable, though transferring files through the MTP 2.0 protocol. 3.0 isn't supported with my phone to ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

No, the transfer over USB using MTP itself does not compress the images or other files.

Of course, your phone's implementation of MTP may do this, or the software you use to receive the files on your computer - but that is unlikely, unless you explicitly enabled it somewhere.

There must be another reason your images look more pixelated on the computer. Maybe the images are displayed differently for some reason?

Comment: Where could I find out if my phone's implementation of MTP / Ubuntu file explorer compresses the images? I tried it on a different, newer computer/monitor with windows 8.1, and the image quality was similar. The color, however, was different, with the monitor looking less vibrant than my phone.